# Email message isn't sent by django on hosting (502 Bad Gateway) but works on localhost

Tags: python, django, email

Email message isn't sent by django on hosting (502 Bad Gateway), but it works on my localhost.  It also works if i send mail from ssh in shell.

This is a view handle form and send data on email, but it works only on my localhost.
On hosting this view, there is an interrupt on the `email.send()` function - 1 minute loading and *502 BAD GATEWAY* nginx error appears.

```
def ContactsView(request):
    form_data = AddContactsForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_data = AddContactsForm(request.POST)
        if form_data.is_valid():
            subject = u'Форма обратной связи'
            recipient = ['snab-service.com@yandex.ru']
            sender = 'snab-service.com@yandex.ru'

            message = u'Имя: ' +   form_data.cleaned_data['name'] + '\n'
            if form_data.cleaned_data['phone']:
                message += u'Телефон: ' + form_data.cleaned_data['phone'] + '\n'
            message += u'Email: ' + form_data.cleaned_data['email'] + '\n'
            if form_data.cleaned_data['message']:
                message += u'Сообщение: ' + form_data.cleaned_data['message']

            email = EmailMessage(subject=subject, body=message, from_email=sender, to=recipient)
            email.send(fail_silently=False)

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contacts/')

    return render(request, 'pages/contacts.html', context = {'form': form_data}, content_type = 'text/html')
```

My email settings found in in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'snab-service.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '***********'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'snab-service.com@yandex.ru'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'snab-service.com@yandex.ru'
```

What can I do to solve this problem? I have tested email send functions in python manage.py shell in ssh and it works.

Comment: Your encoding works looks like you are using Python 2. In Python 2 you have to mark unicode with a `u`, like `u'Имя'. If you miss that, you will get into a large encoding mess.

Comment: Thanks, I correct it. But problem isn't solved.

Comment: It was a problem with a hosting. There is no problem after manual django installing.